# How to call the deepest nested values from a 4-layer nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have pulled some cash flow statements from Yahoo Financials for 9 tickers. It resulted in a 4-layer nested dictionary - dict, list, dict, dict. The ideal results would show the values across 4 layers of the dict all upfront in 1 dataframe, across all tickers, by year.

#### For example:

```
2018-12-31
                                       AMZN              BABA
capitalExpenditures               -13427000000    -35482000000
changeinCash                       10317000000     -4232000000
changetoAccountReceivables         -4615000000      8639000000


2017-12-31
                                   AMZN             BABA
capitalExpenditures            -11955000000    -19628000000
changeinCash                     1922000000     56335000000
changetoAccountReceivables      -4780000000      5690000000
```

Right now, each layer is separated, each ticker each in its own layer, clicking in would bring you to 4 dates each in their own layer, then the final values, making it hard to do comparison across the tickers.

I have looked through the past questions posted here, however most do not reach 4-layers. Also, as my 2nd-layer is a list, I'm unable to proceed beyond that.

Please find below the full code, thanks very much for your advice!

```py
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials
import pandas as pd

ecommerce = ['CTRP', 'EBAY', 'GRUB', 'BABA', 'JD', 'EXPE', 'AMZN', 'BKNG', 'MPNGF']

yahoo_financials_ecommerce = YahooFinancials(ecommerce)

ecommerce_cash_flow_data = yahoo_financials_ecommerce.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'cash')


for k, v in ecommerce_cash_flow_data.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            for k3, v3 in v2.items():
                print(v3) ###AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

def recursive_items(ecommerce_cash_flow_data):
    for key, value in ecommerce_cash_flow_data.items():
        if type(value) is dict:
            yield (key, value)
            yield from recursive_items(value)
        else:
            yield (key, value)

for key, value in recursive_items(ecommerce_cash_flow_data):
    print(key, value)

cashflow = pd.DataFrame(list(ecommerce_cash_flow_data.items())) ###Only shows '0' == cashflowStatementHistory, '1' == every value dumped here thus does not help the situation

cashflow = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(ecommerce_cash_flow_data, columns=[key, value]) for key, value in recursive_items(ecommerce_cash_flow_data)], ignore_index=False)
cashflow ###TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

your_df_from_dict=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ecommerce_cash_flow_data,orient='index')
print(your_df_from_dict) ###helps arrange by tickers, but would like to pull upfront as well the values within each ticker, by cashflow statement objects (capitalExpenditures, changeinCash, etc) and dates.
```

### Raw Nested Dict:

```
{'cashflowStatementHistory': {'AMZN': [{'2018-12-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -13427000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': 10317000000,
                                                       'changeToAccountReceivables': -4615000000,
                                                       'changeToInventory': -1314000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 4414000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': 6352000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 472000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 15341000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': -351000000,
                                                       'investments': 1140000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': -7686000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 10073000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': 2104000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': -7686000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 30723000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -12369000000}},
                                       {'2017-12-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -11955000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': 1922000000,
                                                       'changeToAccountReceivables': -4780000000,
                                                       'changeToInventory': -3583000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 7838000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': 4096000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 283000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 11478000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': 713000000,
                                                       'investments': -3054000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': 9928000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 3033000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': 1897000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': 9928000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 18365000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -27084000000}},
                                       {'2016-12-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -7804000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': 3759000000,
                                                       'changeToAccountReceivables': -3436000000,
                                                       'changeToInventory': -1426000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 6985000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': 2869000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 1724000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 8116000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': -212000000,
                                                       'investments': -2663000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': -3716000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 2371000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': 1067000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': -3716000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 17203000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -9516000000}},
                                       {'2015-12-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -5387000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': 1333000000,
                                                       'changeToAccountReceivables': -1755000000,
                                                       'changeToInventory': -2187000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 5586000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': 2605000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 913000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 5646000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': -374000000,
                                                       'investments': -1066000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': -3882000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 596000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': 798000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': -3882000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 12039000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -6450000000}}],
                              'BABA': [{'2019-03-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -35482000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': -4232000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 8639000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': -6241000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 20551000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 36936000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': 3245000000,
                                                       'investments': -65965000000,
                                                       'issuanceOfStock': 354000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': -4231000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 87886000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromFinancingActivities': 7357000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -8000000,
                                                       'repurchaseOfStock': -10872000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': -7392000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 150975000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -151060000000}},
                                       {'2018-03-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -19628000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': 56335000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 5690000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': 16967000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 10425000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 21885000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': -6065000000,
                                                       'investments': -52936000000,
                                                       'issuanceOfStock': 399000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': 33625000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 64093000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromFinancingActivities': -13665000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -450000000,
                                                       'repurchaseOfStock': -10872000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': 20359000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 125805000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -83764000000}},
                                       {'2017-03-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -11006000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': 38227000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 4611000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': 15100000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 478000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 14185000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': 2038000000,
                                                       'investments': -28582000000,
                                                       'issuanceOfStock': 14694000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': 29333000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 43675000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromFinancingActivities': 2069000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -253000000,
                                                       'repurchaseOfStock': -13182000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': 32914000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 82854000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -79579000000}},
                                       {'2016-03-31': {'capitalExpenditures': -10845000000,
                                                       'changeInCash': -1375000000,
                                                       'changeToLiabilities': 2350000000,
                                                       'changeToNetincome': -28625000000,
                                                       'changeToOperatingActivities': 3366000000,
                                                       'depreciation': 6977000000,
                                                       'effectOfExchangeRate': 466000000,
                                                       'investments': -36162000000,
                                                       'issuanceOfStock': 693000000,
                                                       'netBorrowings': 2478000000,
                                                       'netIncome': 71460000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromFinancingActivities': 778000000,
                                                       'otherCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': 781000000,
                                                       'repurchaseOfStock': -19795000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromFinancingActivities': -15846000000,
                                                       'totalCashFromOperatingActivities': 56836000000,
                                                       'totalCashflowsFromInvestingActivities': -42831000000}}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update 2020-05-01:

- There seems to be some issues with the package returning `None` on many metrics
- [GitHub: YahooFinancials Package Issues Page](https://github.com/JECSand/yahoofinancials/issues)

```py
{'cashflowStatementHistory': {'CTRP': None,
  'EBAY': None,
  'GRUB': None,
  'BABA': None,
  'JD': None,
  'EXPE': None,
  'AMZN': None,
  'BKNG': None,
  'MPNGF': None}}
```

## Original Answer:

### Get Data

```py
ecommerce = ['CTRP', 'EBAY', 'GRUB', 'BABA', 'JD', 'EXPE', 'AMZN', 'BKNG', 'MPNGF']

yahoo_financials_ecommerce = YahooFinancials(ecommerce)

ecommerce_cash_flow_data = yahoo_financials_ecommerce.get_financial_stmts('annual', 'cash')
```

### Create a `dict` of `DataFrames`:

- Iterate through each ticker to create a `DataFrame` and store them all in a `dict`
- `cashflowStatementHistory` is the only first level key, so set data to equal its value.
- The level 2 keys are the ticker symbols.  It's easier to let `pandas` unpack each one into a separate `DataFrame` (e.g. `df_dict['AMZN']`).

  - The `value` of each ticker `key` is a `list` of `dicts` for a given year.
  - The `list comprehension` unpacks each year at this level (e.g. `range(len(data[tkr]))`)
  - `pd.concat` combines the yearly data for each ticker, into a single `DataFrame`.

```py
data = ecommerce_cash_flow_data['cashflowStatementHistory']

df_dict = dict()

for tkr in ecommerce:

    df_dict[tkr] = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data[tkr][x]) for x in range(len(data[tkr]))],
               sort=False, join='outer', axis=1)
```

### Combine `df_dict` with `pd.concat`:

- At this level, `pd.concat` combines all the `DataFrames` in `df_dict` into a single `DataFrame`.

```py
df = pd.concat(df_dict, sort=True)
print(df.head())
```

[image]

### Stack the dates and values:

```py
df_l = pd.DataFrame(df.stack())
df_l.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_l.columns = ['ticker', 'financials', 'date', 'value']
print(df_l.head())
```

[image]

### Pivot into final form:

```py
df_w = df_l.pivot_table(index=['date', 'financials'], columns='ticker', values='value')
print(df_w.head())
```

[image]

Comment: Glad to help.  Nested `dicts` are an evil that afflict us all.